# Will the query be quicker if adding more WHERE conditions?

Tags: performance, query-performance

Assume I have a table `t1` and two queries *q1* and *q2* on `t1`:

```
SELECT xxx FROM t1 WHERE <condition-1>
```

and

```
SELECT xxx FROM t1 WHERE <condition-2>,
```

where `<condition-1>` logically implies `<condition-2>` (i.e., `<condition-1>` is stricter than `<condition-2>`, and the result set of *q1* is a subset of that of *q2*)

**Question:**
Will the response time of *q1* commonly (if ignore extreme cases) be shorter than that of *q2*?

*This question may seem weird, the reason why I ask is I want to figure out some test oracle for the performance test. If the answer to the above question is true, that may serve as a test oracle.*

Comment: What did your tests show?

Comment: This question may seem weird, the reason why I ask is I want to figure out some test oracle for the performance test. If the answer to the above question is true, that may serve as a test oracle. @mustaccio

Comment: the perfmance usaully depends n your indexes and if there are xcostky functions like joins UNION and so on,  further more data you retrieve mire time elapses. create3 a database and try